# System View for URL ID of a Job Link

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, sql

I am creating a DE with all the Clicks using "Data View: Click" (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_click/).

Although it gives me all the information about clicks, it doesn't show the URL ID (which is shown in UI under Tracking > Sends > Job Links). Is there a system view which gives the URL ID for send jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through SQL dataviews - none I've found. 
You could retrieve it through API :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/click-tracking.htm